# Problema com código

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Boas, é o seguinte, tenho este código:

```
    <form style="" name="form">
        <input placeholder="Search..." name="name" id="fn" type="text">
        <input style="display: none ! important;" value="Search" id="search-btn" type="submit">
    </form>

    <div id = "results"></div>


<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#results').load('search_results.php').show();
    $('#search-btn').click(function(){
        showValues();
    });

    $("#fn").keyup(function() {
    if($(this).val().length >= 3) 
        showValues();
    });

    $(function() {
        $('form').bind('submit',function(){
            showValues(); 
            return false; 
        });
    });

    function showValues() {
        $.post('search_results.php', { name: form.name.value },
    function(result){
            $('#results').html(result).show();
        });
    }       
    });
</script>
```

.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
include_once("../../cdn/lib/config.php");
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM films ORDER BY Title");
$stmt->execute();
$films = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    isset( $_REQUEST['name'] ) ? $name=$_REQUEST['name'] : $name='';

    if( empty( $name )){
    foreach($films as $index => $row) {  ?>


    <div id="cover" class="img-thumbnail">
        <div class="audiopt"></div>
            <a href="<? echo $row['ID']; ?>" target="_self">
                <div id="effect" class="img-thumbnail" alt="<? echo $row['Title']; ?>" title="<? echo $row['Title']; ?>"></div>
                    <img src="../../cdn/uploads/films/<? echo $row['Cover']; ?>" alt="<? echo $row['Title']; ?>" title="<? echo $row['Title']; ?>" class="img-thumbnail" />
            </a>
    </div>


    <?
    }
        }



        else{
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM films WHERE Title LIKE ? ORDER BY Title"
   $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->bindValue(1, '%'. $name .'%');
   $stmt->execute();
   $films = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(empty($films)){?>

        <div id="not-found">No films with this title (<b><? echo "$name" ?></b>)</div>

    <?
    }
    else{
    foreach($films as $index => $row) { ?>


    <div id="cover" class="img-thumbnail">
        <div class="audiopt"></div>
            <a href="<? echo $row['ID']; ?>" target="_self">
                <div id="effect" class="img-thumbnail" alt="<? echo $row['Title']; ?>" title="<? echo $row['Title']; ?>"></div>
                    <img src="../../cdn/uploads/films/<? echo $row['Cover']; ?>" alt="<? echo $row['Title']; ?>" title="<? echo $row['Title']; ?>" class="img-thumbnail" />
            </a>
    </div>


        <?
        }
        }
        }
        ?>
```

O problema é: no **xampp** esse código funciona perfeitamente, mas no meu site não. Faço a pesquisa e ele simplesmente não reage. Alguém me pode ajudar? Apenas no início me dá os `dados` todos. Mas quando pesquiso nada acontece.

Comment: Se você acesar o arquivo php que retonar o negocio, a tela fica em branco ou exibe algum erro? Adicione essas linhas no inicio dos php e veja se aparece algum erro: `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: `Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'tvfootba'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/user/public_html/PASTA/search_results.php on line 10

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/user/public_html/PASTA/search_results.php on line 10` deu isso

Comment: vc está só usando o PDO certo? o mysql_*(antigo) n faz parte do seu código.

Comment: certo, mas no **xampp** deu tudo certo..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para usar [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) é necessário uma conexão ativa como você não conectou o banco com as funções antigas mysql_* remova a linha a baixo.

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string( $name );
```

Sanitize as entradas do usuário com prepared statements, o primeiro passo é remover `mysql_real_escape_string` do código, depois converta a string sql em uma consulta preparada com método `prepare()`, agora faça o bind de `$name` com a interrogação usando `bindValue()` o primeiro argumento é a posição da interrogação e o segundo o valor que será atribuido a ela e por último obtenha o resultado da consulta com `fetchAll()`.

Mude:

```
else{
   $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM films WHERE Title LIKE '%$name%' ORDER BY Title");
   $stmt->execute();
   $films = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Para:

```
else{
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM films WHERE Title LIKE ? ORDER BY Title"
   $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->bindValue(1, '%'. $name .'%');
   $stmt->execute();
   $films = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: fiz isso e agora aparece-me tudo branco ..

Comment: @thecreator, estou revisando aqui logo atualizo

Comment: esta bem, ficarei a espera. e desde já muito obrigado

Comment: vc trocou o `query`por `prepare()`, verifique também se está caindo no else que tem a consulta com o where.

Comment: @thecreator, veja o comentario anterior, fiz o teste so com a consulta funcinou, agora pode ser que nao esteja caindo em algum if/else

Comment: http://prntscr.com/70igxo erro e capaz de estar aqui, nao? xd

Comment: continua a nao funcionar, atualizei o codigo

Comment: @thecreator, que faltou o `;` em `$sql = "SELECT ..."`, tbm não precisa de dois `else` seguidos, deixa um so.

Comment: Funcionou, obrigadao !

Comment: Obrigado pelo tempo que disponibilizou a ajudar-me !

Comment: @thecreator, acho melhor voltar a edição da sua pergunta, ela fica meio estranho, pq um dos motivos do primeiro erro era a funação mysql_real_escape. O outro erro foi pq eu esqueci do `;` na minha resposta xD.